# Unittest with angular, karma and es6 - injecting a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, webpack, karma-runner

I'm trying to write a test for this directive:

```
export default angular.module('app.page.section.accountBalance', [])
    .directive('accountBalance', accountBalanceConfig);

function accountBalanceConfig() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        template: require('./account-balance.tpl.html'),
        controller: accountBalanceController,
        controllerAs: 'accountBalance'
    }
}

class accountBalanceController {
    constructor($scope, domFactory, userService, $filter) {
       // controller logic
    }
}
```

As you can see, the directive's controller depend on `domFactory` which is a custom service I created that compiles the DOM:

```
export class DomGenerator {
    /**
     * @constructor
     * inject dependencies
     */
    constructor() {
        'ngInject';
    }

    // service logic
}
```

This is the test:

```
import { DomGenerator } from '../../shared/services/dom-genereator/dom-generator.srv';
import compile from '../compile/compile.drv';
import module from './account-balance.drv';

describe('account balance', () => {
    var $rootScope, $compile, $location, $window, $document, userService, domFactory, $provide;

    beforeEach(() => {
        domFactory = new DomGenerator();
        userService = new UserData();
    });

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(compile.name));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(module.name));

    beforeEach(inject(($injector) => {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    }));

    it('renders account balance widget headline', () => {
        var element =  $compile(`<account-balance data="{headline: {title: 'account balance'}}"></account-balance>`)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(element.html()).to.contain('account balance');
    });
});

class UserData {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: domFactoryProvider <- domFactory
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=domFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20domFactory
    at webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:68:0 <- spec.bundle.js:16824:13
    at webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:4511:0 <- spec.bundle.js:21267:20
    at Object.getService [as get] (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:4664:0 <- spec.bundle.js:21420:40)
    at webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:4516:0 <- spec.bundle.js:21272:46
    at getService (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:4664:0 <- spec.bundle.js:21420:40)
    at injectionArgs (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:4688:0 <- spec.bundle.js:21444:59)
    at Object.invoke (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:4710:0 <- spec.bundle.js:21466:19)
    at $controllerInit (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:10354:0 <- spec.bundle.js:27110:35)
    at nodeLinkFn (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:9263:0 <- spec.bundle.js:26019:35)
    at compositeLinkFn (webpack:///~/angular/angular.js:8620:0 <- spec.bundle.js:25376:14)
```

Which means that I didn't inject the service to the directive's controller.
What am I doing wrong?

Isn't

```
beforeEach(() => {
            domFactory = new DomGenerator();
            userService = new UserData();
        });`
```

enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like that , You should mock the service (Use sinon).

```
import accountBalanceController from 'path for account balance controller'
// import accountBalanceConfig
// import html template
import { DomGenerator } from '../../shared/services/dom-genereator/dom-generator.srv';
import compile from '../compile/compile.drv';
import module from './account-balance.drv';
import sinon from 'sinon'

describe('account balance', () => {
  let $rootScope, makeController,DomGeneratorFactory,$scope,$filter,userService;

  beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_,_$scope_,_$filter_) => {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = _$scope_;
    $filter = _$filter_;
    DomGeneratorFactory =  sinon.createStubInstance(DomGenerator);
    // Create mock to user Service
    makeController = () => {
      return new accountBalanceController($scope, DomGeneratorFactory, userService, $filter);
    };
  }));

  describe('Controller', () => {
    // controller specs
    it('has a name property [REMOVE]', () => { // erase if removing this.name from the controller
      let controller = makeController();
      expect(controller).to.have.property('name');
    });
    it('includes the intended template', () => {
      expect(accountBalanceConfig.template).to.equal(htmlTemplate);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Applied your code. Created a mock to user service too. now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at webpack:/webpack/bootstrap%208abd7032bd3ba4917b19:19:0 <- spec.bundle.js:20`